# Compiling both C and C++ sources in Cython

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, clang, cython, clang++

I'm trying to compile both C and C++ sources at the same time in Cython. This is my current setup:

-setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from distutils.extension import Extension
import os

language = "c++"
extra_compile_flags = ["-std=c++17"]
os.environ["CC"] = "clang++"

ext_modules = [
    Extension(
        name="Dummy",
        sources=["mydummy.pyx", "source1.cpp","source2.c"],
        language=language,
        extra_compile_args=extra_compile_flags,
   )
]

ext_modules = cythonize(ext_modules)

setup(
    name="myapp",
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
)
```

-compile command:

```
python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace --verbose
```

In the log I get the following message:

```
clang++ -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I. -I/usr/include/python3.6m -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c /path/source2.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/./path/source2.o -std=c++17 -O3
clang: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated [-Wdeprecated]
```

The compilation goes trough, but the warning looks pretty nasty. How can I get rid of it? 
The naive solution

```
os.environ["CC"] = "clang"
os.environ["CXX"] = "clang++"
```

is failing with `error: invalid argument '-std=c++17' not allowed with 'C'`

Answer (score 5):

gcc (or clang) is just a frontend and it calls the appropriate compiler (c- or c++-compiler) given the file-extension of the compiled file (.c means it should be compiled with c-compiler and .cpp means it should be compiled with c++-compiler), see for example this similar [SO-issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48633172/5769463).

Thus there is no need to set the compiler to "clang++", as it will happen automatically.

However, cython needs to know that it has to produce a cpp-file (along with accepting c++-syntax) and not a c-file. Also the linker has to know, that it has to link against cpp-libaries (it is done automatically if g++/clang++ is used for linking). Thus we need to add `language = "c++"` to the `Extension`'s definition, as suggested in DavidW's answer - this will take care of the last two problems.

The remaining problem is, that we would to like use different compiler options (`-std=c++17` only for cpp-files) for different source-files. This can be achieved using a less known command [`build_clib`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f501db2b93a9d3d840b6fb38d6bdda8bcc400d4a/Lib/distutils/command/build_clib.py):

```py
#setup.py:

from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from distutils.extension import Extension

ext_modules = [
    Extension(
        name="mydummy",
        sources=["mydummy.pyx", "source1.cpp"]
        language="c++",
        extra_compile_args=["-std=c++17"],
   )
]

ext_modules = cythonize(ext_modules)

myclib = ('myclib', {'sources': ["source2.c"]})

setup(
    name="mydummy",
    libraries=[myclib],
    ext_modules=ext_modules,
)
```

And now building either with

```
python setup.py build --verbose
```

or

```
python setup.py build_clib --verbose build_ext -i --verbose
```

will first build a simple static library consisting of C-code and link it to the resulting extension consisting of c++-code.

The above code uses the default compilation flags when building the static library, which should be enough in your case.

`distutils` [doesn't offer](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f501db2b93a9d3d840b6fb38d6bdda8bcc400d4a/Lib/distutils/command/build_clib.py#L198) the possibility to specify additinal flags, so if it is necessary we have either to switch to [`setuptools`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/1d03fdc94c3676a5b675ec7d818d48c6a772fb49/setuptools/command/build_clib.py#L86) which offers this functionality, or to patch the `build_clib` command.

For the second alternative we have to add the following to the above `setup.py`-file:

```py
#setup.py
...
# adding cflags to build_clib
from distutils import log
from distutils.command.build_clib import build_clib

# use original implementation but with tweaked build_libraries!
class build_clib_with_cflags(build_clib):
    def build_libraries(self, libraries):
            for (lib_name, build_info) in libraries:
                sources = build_info.get('sources')
                if sources is None or not isinstance(sources, (list, tuple)):
                    raise DistutilsSetupError(
                           "in 'libraries' option (library '%s'), "
                           "'sources' must be present and must be "
                           "a list of source filenames" % lib_name)
                sources = list(sources)

                log.info("building '%s' library", lib_name)


                macros = build_info.get('macros')
                include_dirs = build_info.get('include_dirs')
                cflags = build_info.get('cflags')                    # HERE we add cflags
                objects = self.compiler.compile(sources, 
                                                output_dir=self.build_temp,
                                                macros=macros,
                                                include_dirs=include_dirs,
                                                extra_postargs=cflags,        # HERE we use cflags
                                                debug=self.debug)


                self.compiler.create_static_lib(objects, lib_name,
                                                output_dir=self.build_clib,
                                                debug=self.debug)

...
setup(
    ...
    cmdclass={'build_clib': build_clib_with_cflags}, # use our class instead of built-in!
)
```

and now we can add additional compile flags to the library-definitions (the previous step can be skipped if `setuptools` is used):

```
...
myclib = ('myclib', {'sources': ["source2.c"], 'cflags' : ["-O3"]})
...
```

Comment: I think you misinterpreted a small bit of my answer: I'm suggesting not using `language=c++` in setup.py (it's also already in the original question). Instead I'm suggesting only putting it in the pyx file. The rest of the answer looks like a reasonable way to specify different command-line arguments for different sources

Comment: I guess my other concern would be: is the extension linked against `myclib`, or is `myclib` just built?

Comment: @DavidW I'm pretty sure that  `# distutils: language = c++` has the same effect as setting via `language`-argument of `Extension` (it is not just producing cpp-file from pyx-file but also using g++ for linking).

Comment: @DavidW distutils takes care of passing the built `libmyclib.a` to linker when the actual extensions are linked.

Comment: I'd thought that putting the language in setup.py also forced it on any .c files listed in the `sources` (which wouldn't affect your answer anyway). This appears to be wrong, so I've deleted my answer since this was the main point I was making. I also wasn't sure that `libraries` were linked to everything by default (and there's no documentation). I guess you've tested this so I'll be quiet now...