# Specifying Exact CPU Instruction Set with Cythonized Python Wheels

Tags: python, cython

I have a Python package with a native extension compiled by [Cython](https://cython.org/). Due to some performance needs, the compilation is done with `-march=native, -mtune=native` flags. This basically enables the compiler to use any of the available ISA extensions.

Additionally, we keep a non-cythonized, pure-python version of this package. It should be used in environments which are less performance sensitive.

Hence, in total we have two versions published:

- Cythonized wheel built for a very specific platform
- Pure-python wheel.

Some other packages depend on this package, and some of the machines are a bit different than the one that the package was compiled on. Since we used `-march=native`, as a result we get `SIGILL`, since some ISA extension is missing on the server.

So, in essence, I'd like to somehow make `pip` disregard the native wheel if the host CPU is not compatible with the wheel.

The native wheel does have the `cp37` and platform name, but I don't see a way to define a more granular ISA requirements here. I can always use `--implementation` flags for pip, but I wonder if there's a better way for pip to differentiate among different ISAs.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pip infrastructure doesn't support such granularity.

I think a better approach would be to have two versions of the Cython-extension compiled: with `-march=native` and without, to install both and to decide at the run time which one should be loaded.

Here is a proof of concept.

The first hoop to jump: how to check at run time which instructions are supported by CPU/OS combination. For the simplicity we will check for AVX (this [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6121792/5769463) has more details) and I offer only a gcc-specific (see also [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=85100)) solution - called `impl_picker.pyx`:

```py
cdef extern from *:
    """
    int cpu_supports_avx(void){
        return __builtin_cpu_supports("avx");
    }
    """
    int cpu_supports_avx()

def cpu_has_avx_support():
    return cpu_supports_avx() != 0
```

The second problem: the pyx-file and the module must have the same name. To avoid code duplication, the actual code is in a pxi-file:

```py
# worker.pxi
cdef extern from *:
    """   
    int compiled_with_avx(void){
        #ifdef __AVX__
            return 1;
        #else
            return 0;
        #endif
    }
    """
    int compiled_with_avx()

def compiled_with_avx_support():
    return compiled_with_avx() != 0
```

As one can see, the function `compiled_with_avx_support` will [yield different results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28939652/5769463), depending on whether it was compiled with `-march=native` or not.

And now we can define two versions of the module just by including the actual code from the *.pxi-file. One module called  `worker_native.pyx`:

```py
# distutils: extra_compile_args=["-march=native"]

include "worker.pxi"
```

and `worker_fallback.pyx`:

```py
include "worker.pxi"
```

Building everything, e.g. via `cythonize -i -3 *.pyx`, it can be used as follows:

```py
from impl_picker import cpu_has_avx_support

# overhead once when imported:
if cpu_has_avx_support():
    import worker_native as worker
else:
    print("using fallback worker")
    import worker_fallback as worker

print("compiled_with_avx_support:", worker.compiled_with_avx_support())
```

On my machine the above would lead to `compiled_with_avx_support: True`, on older machines the "slower" `worker_fallback` will be used and the result will be `compiled_with_avx_support: False`.

---

The goal of this post is not to give a working `setup.py`, but just to outline the idea how one could achieve the goal of picking correct version at the run time. Obviously, the setup.py could be quite more complicated: e.g. one would need to compile multiple c-files with different compiler settings (see this [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59364990/5769463), how this could be achieved).