# Enable CPU dispatch in Cython

Tags: cython

Is it possible to do CPU dispatching in Cython?

Some info on CPU dispatching:

https://johnnysswlab.com/cpu-dispatching-make-your-code-both-portable-and-fast/

https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/simd/how-it-works.html

Comment: Here is an example how this could work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70490127/5769463